# how to compare string without case sensitive using c#?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to compare two string without case sensitive using c#?
Am using the below codes.

```
string b = "b";
int c = string.Compare(a, b);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

By explicitly specifying it:

```
int c = string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: You should use OrdinalIgnoreCase or CurrentCultureIgnoreCase depending on your needs. You normally don't want to use the InvariantCultures for comparisons - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919

Comment: @Manfred Thanks I was thinking about String.Equals(stringA, stringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
int c = string.Compare(a, b,true);
```

Comment: the last argument should be `true` (ignoreCase)

Answer (score 1):

convert them to lower case then compare, There you go:

```
        string b = "b";
        string a = "";
        int c = string.Compare(a.ToLower(), b.ToLower());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String.Equals(stringA, stringB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```